# Short a jquery code

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover, long-integer

I made a simple animation Jquery code, but this code is too long, and I wondering if it's possible to shorten these long lines :

My Jsfiddle exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/ZDhzJ/2/

```
$("#UN").mouseover(function() {  
    $("#UNbis").stop().animate({opacity: 1}); 
});
$("#UN").mouseout(function() {  
    $("#UNbis").stop().animate({opacity: 0}); 
});

$("#DEUX").mouseover(function() {  
    $("#DEUXbis").stop().animate({opacity: 1}); 
});
$("#DEUX").mouseout(function() {  
    $("#DEUXbis").stop().animate({opacity: 0}); 
});

$("#TROIS").mouseover(function() {  
    $("#TROISbis").stop().animate({opacity: 1}); 
});
$("#TROIS").mouseout(function() {  
    $("#TROISbis").stop().animate({opacity: 0}); 
});

$("#QUATRE").mouseover(function() {  
    $("#QUATREbis").stop().animate({opacity: 1}); 
});
$("#QUATRE").mouseout(function() {  
    $("#QUATREbis").stop().animate({opacity: 0}); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the selector and event handler, add `bis` to the targeted ID :

```
$('#UN, #DEUX, #TROIS, #QUATRE').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('#'+this.id+'bis').stop().animate({opacity: e.type=='mouseenter'?1:0});
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDhzJ/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

- Add a class `myDiv` to the divs to be hovered upon
- Find the `span` inside the divs using the function scope.

**JS:**

```
$(".myDiv").mouseover(function() {  
    $(this).find('span').stop().animate({opacity: 1}); });
$(".myDiv").mouseout(function() {  
    $(this).find('span').stop().animate({opacity: 0}); });
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDhzJ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#UN, #DEUX, #TROIS, #QUATRE').hover(function(e) {// work as mouseover
    $('#'+this.id+'bis').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
},
function(e){//work as mouseout
    $('#'+this.id+'bis').stop().animate({opacity: 0});

});
```

can try with **[hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)**

see **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/ZDhzJ/8/)**